# C++ linked classes weird behaviour

Tags: c++, class

The following code represents the strategy design pattern.

Consider the following program structure:

//base.hpp

```
#ifndef BASE_HPP
#define BASE_HPP

class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual int solve() = 0;
};

#endif
```

//derived.hpp

```
#include "base.hpp"

class Derived: public Base {
  public:
    virtual int solve() { return 77; }
};
```

I have a client.cpp which receives a context of Derived

```
#include "client.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void Client::operate() {
  std::cout << solver_.solve() << std::endl;

}
```

This is the header file of client:

```
#include "base.hpp"

class Client {
  public:
    Client(Base& b): solver_(b) {}
    void operate();
  private:
    Base& solver_;
};
```

My main: test.cpp

```
#include "client.hpp"
#include "derived.hpp"

int main() {
  Derived d;
  Client c(d);
  c.operate() ;
}
```

I would expect it to print 77, but the program doesn't print anything at all.

Client receives a context to Derived by it's constructor and stores it as Base& solver_;
First, the operate method of Client is called, which calls the appropriate solve method of class that derives from Base. In this case, Derived.

Right, that should output 77, but it doesn't. The program compiles fine and no errors, just clean exit. Any ideas ?

I compiled it using following command:

```
g++ -o program.exe client.cpp test.cpp
```

I'm using GCC version 5.3.0

Comment: [works for me](http://ideone.com/QZBLPI). Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Thank you, i think this might be a compiler issue. What version of gcc are you using ?

Comment: Try deleting all object files (*.o) and the executable and recompiling. If you're using something like make, run make clean.

Comment: @ArthurTacca That didn't help, still no output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that some of the libraries were not linked by g++, namely libstdc++-6.dll.

This problem can be fixed by using -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ options

The definition gives: 
"When the g++ program is used to link a C++ program, it normally automatically links against libstdc++. If libstdc++ is available as a shared library, and the -static option is not used, then this links against the shared version of libstdc++. That is normally fine. However, it is sometimes useful to freeze the version of libstdc++ used by the program without going all the way to a fully static link. The -static-libstdc++ option directs the g++ driver to link libstdc++ statically, without necessarily linking other libraries statically."

See: [libstdc++-6.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404636/libstdc-6-dll-not-found)