# Dynamic link error when trying to run MinGW compiled C++ code

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I've done some googling and everything already but none of the solutions online exactly match my situation. So I have one project which has the files

- Main.cpp
- BankAccount.hpp
- BanckAccount.cpp
- GoCardAccount.hpp
- GoCardAccount.cpp

And when I compile it, it is completely fine. But running it gives me the following image: [image]

The things I have tried:

1. Reinstalling MinGW
2. Putting the libstdc++6.dll in System32
3. (The only thing that works) putting the libstdc++6.dll in the project directory.

I feel like this is not the best option. Especially since if I write a small "Hello World" program, then the error does not appear.

Is there any way of actually fixing this?

Comment: How do you compile and link? Can you post the command you are using?

Comment: You could try to link statically as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404636/libstdc-6-dll-not-found

Comment: I am using `g++ -std=c++14 *.cpp -o main.exe`.