# the code execution cannot proceed because libstdc++-6.dll was not found

Tags: c++

So I compile a C++ file to an exe for my friend to test on windows, but when my friend run the file, it shows

> the code execution cannot proceed because libstdc++-6.dll was not found

How can I fix this?

I compile the file on linux manjaro with mingw64 using this code:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.exe main.cpp
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [libstdc++-6.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404636/libstdc-6-dll-not-found)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405064/3828077) answer.

Comment: Does you friend of mingw installed on his computer? If you complied this on your PC using mingw and he does have the mingw DLLs installed on his computer it will not run. The same happens with Visual Studio if you don't install the redistributable installed. Or you could end him the DLL and he can place it next to the exe an it will find it