# how can i fix "libstdc++-6.dll not found" error in my c++ program?

Tags: c++, mingw

recently I realized my c++ program was detected as a virus and I think it must be a compiler problem. so I uninstalled my compiler and reinstall it through msys2. the output is ok in my system but when I run EXE outputs created by a new compiler in a Virtual machine or another system I've got this error: **libstdc++-6.dll not found**

I don't have any idea how to fix this problem. I appreciate any help.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grReS.png)

Comment: Search for that file in your OS and put it in the same folder as your executable possibly packaging it in an installer package to install on the other computer. This documentation tells you how and where your OS looks for required dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: Or rather not in the OS, but in your compiler installation. Should be in the same directory as `gcc.exe`. You can also use `ntldd` package to automatically determine all needed dlls, but you need to filter out the ones that come from the Windows itself.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat how can i use ntldd package?

Comment: Install it (e.g. for MINGW64 it's named `mingw-w64-x86_64-ntldd`), run `ntldd -R my_program.exe`, then filter out any dlls not installed by MSYS2 (for MINGW64 that would be anything outside `/mingw64/bin`), then copy those dlls next to the exe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [libstdc++-6.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404636/libstdc-6-dll-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Some people call this DLL hell, but that's usually because they don't really understand completely how shared libraries work on Windows.

You can avoid DLL dependancies by building your .exe file with linker flag `-static` and linking with the necessary dependencies static library files (`*.a`).
Specifically for the C++ standard library `libstdc++-6.dll` you will need to specify linker flag `-static-libstdc++`.

Or you can use shared libraries (`*.dll`), but then you need to distribute them in the same folder as the `.exe` file.

I wrote a tool called `copypedeps` as part of https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps to copy `.exe` files along with all the required `.dll` files.