# The applications I made with C++ work on my own computer, but on different computers it gives libstdc++-6.dll not found ,libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll not found

Tags: c++, sfml

The applications I made with C++ sfml works on my own computer, but on my friends computers, it gives **libstdc++-6.dll not found and ligcc_s_dw2-1.dll not found errors**. **I'm using visual studio code**. I want applications to be opened on my friends computers **without installing mingw to my friends computers**, what can I do?

My makefile :

```
all: compile link run

compile:
    g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp

link:
    g++ main.o -o main -L src/lib -mwindows -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

run:
    main
```

Comment: Your friends' computers use different versions of the C++ compiler and libraries. C++ programs can use the same versions that they are built with. Highly experienced C++ developers will know how to build and link their code to include all necessarily libraries as part of the deal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404636/libstdc-6-dll-not-found